# Не работает button и JS в расширении

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-extension

Разрабатываю Firefox расширение, при разработке столкнулся с двумя проблемами - button не работает и JS не срабатывает. Коды ниже

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Image URL" id="urlinput"/>
        <br>
        <p style="font-size:32px;text-align:center;" id="status">Chat field: </p>
        <select id="chatselect">
            <option>Darker</option>
            <option>Lighter</option>
            <option>Black</option>
            <option>Don't fill</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        
        <button id="submit" type="submit" value=".">Submit</button>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

```
document.body.getElementById("status").innerText = "3Done!";
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.body.getElementById("status").innerText = "1Done!";
    if (e.target.id == "submit") {
        let url = document.body.getElementById("urlinput").value
        let mode = document.body.getElementById("chatselect").options[document.body.getElementById("chatselect").selectedIndex]; //fun
        document.body.getElementById("status").innerText = "2Done!";
        browser.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "change.js"
        });
        var gettingActiveTab = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
        gettingActiveTab.then((tabs) => {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {url: url, mode: mode});
        });
    }
});
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: script.js лежит рядом с html файлом?

Comment: @SaNFeeD разумеется

Comment: Попробуйте написать так - src="./index.js"

Comment: @SaNFeeD не робит

Comment: Что пишет? Можете в ответе дополнить?

Comment: @SaNFeeD помогли, без вас не додумался бы консоль почекать. Ошибка заключалась в том что вместо `document.body.getElement` надо было писать `document.getElement`. Спасибо

Comment: @kingley, если вопрос для вас закрыт, можете ответить на него сами.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в ошибке в коде (вместо `document.body.getElement` надо было писать `document.getElement`)